# Goto was unexpected at this time?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a little connect four game and whenever I hit enter without typing anything into the console it says that goto was unexpected at this time All I want it to dos go back to :X for now if there is no user input. Any help would be aappreciated.

```
:X
cls
echo --------------
echo Connect Four X
echo --------------
echo.
echo CHOOSE A COLUMN
echo.
echo.
echo  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
echo.
echo (%a6%) (%b6%) (%c6%) (%d6%) (%e6%) (%f6%) (%g6%)
echo.
echo (%a5%) (%b5%) (%c5%) (%d5%) (%e5%) (%f5%) (%g5%)
echo.
echo (%a4%) (%b4%) (%c4%) (%d4%) (%e4%) (%f4%) (%g4%)
echo.
echo (%a3%) (%b3%) (%c3%) (%d3%) (%e3%) (%f3%) (%g3%)
echo.
echo (%a2%) (%b2%) (%c2%) (%d2%) (%e2%) (%f2%) (%g2%)
echo.
echo (%a1%) (%b1%) (%c1%) (%d1%) (%e1%) (%f1%) (%g1%)
echo.
echo ---------------------------
echo.
echo.
set /p xchoice=:
if %xchoice% == 1 goto xcheck1
if %xchoice% == 2 goto xcheck2
if %xchoice% == 3 goto xcheck3
if %xchoice% == 4 goto xcheck4
if %xchoice% == 5 goto xcheck5
if %xchoice% == 6 goto xcheck6
if %xchoice% == 7 goto xcheck7
goto X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'`

IF syntax is if string1 operator string2 action.

You need

```
if "%possiblyemptyvariable%"=="1" goto ...
```

Comment: There still could be problems if the value already contains quotes along with poison characters and/or spaces. The only absolutely safe way to compare is using delayed expansion. Enclosing quotes should still be used with delayed expansion if you do search and replace or substring operation with the expansion.